# Changing the IP address and using the findtr command

Tags: powershell, cmd, ip, ip-address, powershell-3.0

I'm not sure if CMD is really capable of doing this so I'm open to powershell advice also.

What I'm trying to do is add 20 to the last octet of the Ip Address:

> 10.134.12.150

to

> 10.134.12.170

I believe the process is:

1. Find the IPv4 string within ipconfig
2. Find the 4th "."
3. +20 after the "."

Answer (score 2):

Split the address and cast the result to an array of bytes. Add 20 to the last element (e.g -1) then join back the numbers

```
PS> $octet = [byte[]]('10.134.12.150' -split '\.')
10
134
12
150

PS> $octet[-1]+=20
PS> $octet
10
134
12
170

PS> $octet -join '.'
10.134.12.170
```

Comment: How can you convert a command such as "ipconfig" to an array of bytes?

Comment: ipconfig output includes text and ip addresses. Do you want the current ip address parsed the same way?

Comment: Sorry being so late on the reply. The problem I'm having: 
$ip = ipconfig | findstr "IPv4"

I'm trying to set the IPv4 address to the $ip variable
But it can't convert the value to "System.Byte", which is needed to cast an array of bytes.

Comment: ipconfig | findstr "IPv4" returns more than just an ip address. Try this to extract just the address: $ip = (ipconfig | findstr "IPv4").split(':')[1].trim()